# How can I fully complete Antichamber demo?

Tags: antichamber

I have played the [May 2010 demo](https://www.moddb.com/games/unreal-tournament-3/addons/hazard-the-journey-of-life) of a game called *Antichamber*, formerly known as *Hazard: The Journey of Life*. Walkthroughs are available on Youtube, see for instance [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEgXJpINbFs) if you are not afraid of spoilers and want to get a glimpse at the game. Yet these are a kind of speedrun, and I would be interested in a complete playthrough of the demo.

Here is the map of the chambers at the end of my playthrough:

[image: map]

Here are the achievements I got at the end of my playthrough:

[image: achievements]

I have put red dots at the locations of missing chambers. I am not sure these are available in the demo, since:

1. Some of them are listed, *at the very end of the demo*, under a caption "Look at all of these unsolved puzzles." and a remark about the upcoming full game.
2. At the end of the demo, there is a no-return point when we get a binary gun (addition/subtraction), which would prove helpful in my opinion in some puzzles.

So, has anyone played this game already? And have you solved additional puzzles?

Comment: The puzzles that require a binary gun to advance aren't solvable in the demo.

Comment: The game will be released on Steam on January 31, 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, the demo is nowhere to be found on the Internet. It is most likely nobody except the dev would be able to answer this question. However, the dev is busy with the release of the game in December. Therefore, I will accept as answer the comment of Merus:

> The puzzles that require a binary gun to advance aren't solvable in
>   the demo.

Comment: Please have a look at [IndiePubGames' entry for Hazard](http://www.indiepubgames.com/game/Hazard:_The_Journey_Of_Life) which does include a download link.